# Is Widows tab-order == HTML Z-order?

Tags: html, windows, z-order, tab-ordering

If I use a Windows program to generate HTML forms, can I say that Windows tab-order == HTML Z-order?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The [TAB order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_order) is the order in which controls receive focus when you use the TAB key. The [Z order (or Z index)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_index) is a 3D type index which dictates which UI elements will appear above (over) others.

Comment: The HTML equivalent is the [tabindex](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-tabindex) (and it is almost always a bad idea to mess with it).

Comment: @David Dorward, +1 - that is actually what I wanted to know. If you re-post as an answer, I will award you the question. Thanks.

Comment: It isn't what you asked though. @slugster answered that and deserves the tick.

Comment: Cheers @David, appreciated :)

Comment: +1 to each of you, the answer to slug & kudos to david, who read my mind & wouldn't accept the reward for it. Thanks all round for such a quick & comprehensive answer